# Return an existing instance if a condition is true

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a JS class which is supposed to wrap an HTML element and change some of it's properties, children, etc.

I can know if that element has been "touched", or wrapped already, but I'm setting some internal properties of the `this` object when returned by the constructor, and if it's in two places at once, the properties won't change together. For example:

```
window.my_class = function( id ){ 

    // find the element
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);

    // make sure it's a valid HTML element in the page
    if(!this.element)
        return console.error('No such element: #'+id);

    // wrap jquery
    var jq = $(this.element);
    var my_class = jq.data('my_class');

    // was this HTML element already "touched" by our class? does it have a corresponding instance of the `my_class` class?
    if(!$.isEmptyObject(my_class)){

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Here's the dilemma: 
        // how do I make `this` point to the old `my_class` ?
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this = my_class; // <- I don't think this is okay
        return false;
    }

    // add elements to class
    this.id = id;
    this.initialized = true;
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#f0f';
    this.innerHTML = '<h1>PARSED</h1>';
    this.something = false;

    // save "this" for later use
    jq.data('my_class',this);
}

// the rest of the class methods go here
window.my_class.prototype.do_something = function(){ 
    this.something = 'changed';
}
```

Now imagine we have a `<div id="wrap_me">` on that page:

```
// the div gets initialized here
var instance1 = new my_class('wrap_me'); 

// the div doesn't get initialized again, but `instance2` 
// should now be the same with `instance1`; except it isn't
var instance2 = new my_class('wrap_me');

// changes the "this.something" property internally
instance2.do_something();

// this prints false. should print true in a perfect world
console.log( instance2.something===instance1.something );
```

I know there's an alternative way around this by wrapping my_class() in a function and return instances from it, but if it's possible without wrapping the class, it would be nicer for code semantics.

Comment: you probably need to use `new` to be able to use `this` inside constructor function, AND just return `my_class` instead of assigning it to `this` so that `this = my_class; return false;` becomes `return my_class`. `this` can't be on left side of assignment operator.

Comment: @Ejay I forgot about the `new` keyword, I've entered it now. Regardless of what you return from `new my_class()`, it will only return the new instance of the class, the one being constructed.

Comment: Maybe you should check out the `jQuery plugin pattern` instead. Wrapping elements and creating instances shouldn’t be so tightly mixed: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: you mean `console.log( instance1 === instance2);` logs `false`?

Comment: @Ejay yes it logs false.

Comment: @David AFAIK you can't easily extend or modify the methods in a jQuery plugin or widget. `my_class` needs to be extensible by developers in the future by not modifying the original JS file.

Comment: _After_ adding `return my_class;` in the `if` statement, it logs true for me (think)

Comment: @Ejay Have you put new keyword for initializing my_class? If you haven't then the instance returned by `return my_class` would be equal (===) to the previous instance.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL What I mean is that you should use jQuery for selecting elements and saving the instances, then use your own pattern for functionality (see my answer)

Comment: @Салман yes certainly I did (see my first comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an alternative pattern for you. I would use jQuery for dom/selector stuff and save the instance in the `data` object in the jQuery initiator. This way you will return only one "instance" of the class for each element:

```
$.fn.my_class = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var inst = $(this).data('my_class')
        if ( !inst ) { // only create a new instance if none was saved from before
            $(this).data('my_class', new my_class(this))
        }
        return this // always return this so you don’t break the chain
    })
}
```

And then:

```
function my_class(elem) {
    this.element = elem
    this.something = false
    // etc...
}

my_class.prototype.do_something = function() {
    this.something = true
}

var inst1 = $('#my_class').my_class().data('my_class') // you need to use `.data` to get the instance
var inst2 = $('#my_class').my_class().data('my_class')
inst2.do_something()
console.log(inst1.something === true)
```